# SUM and SUMIF with an array argument

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sum, sumifs

This works:

```
=SUM(SUMIF(A2:A9, {"Allen","James","Carol"} , F2:F9))
```

This does NOT work :

```
=SUM(SUMIF(A2:A9, {G2,G3,G4} , F2:F9))
```

G2, G3, G4 are cell addresses

I also tried this (This does NOT work as well):

Create a string in cell A15 which resolves to {"Allen","James","Carol"}

```
=SUM(SUMIF(A2:A9, {$A$15} , F2:F9))
```

Any help greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

Use `=SUM(SUMIF(A2:A9, G2:G4, F2:F9))`.

Since this is an array formula, you may then have to confirm the formula with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, depending on your version of Excel,

Comment: The magic of CTRL + Shift + Enter - that did the trick. Much thanks!!
I also learned that EVERY time an array formula is edited - You have to hit CTRL + Shift + Enter.

Comment: @VijaySuri - yes. With one qualification - Ctrl + Shift + Enter is not needed in newer versions of Excel.

Comment: Starting with which version? I am using Microsoft Excel for Office 365 (MSO)  16.0.11328.20512 32-bit and I had to use Ctrl + Shift + Enter.

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/dynamic-array-formulas-in-non-dynamic-aware-excel-696e164e-306b-4282-ae9d-aa88f5502fa2 for more details.

Comment: Did some research - even though MS has been talking about dynamic arrays since 2018, it is still not available to all users - only "Preview" users. 

https://www.fm-magazine.com/news/2019/feb/excel-dynamic-arrays-modifications-201920674.html .

The rest of us will have to wait :-( .

Comment: You should sign up to be an Insider then - it was fairly easy. But I thought dynamic arrays were getting the full rollout this year... idk.